# Is there a way to delete built in Dynamics in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

As states the title, I could delete only user crafted dynamics, not the built in. Am I missing anything or should I go looking for some files to delete?

I menaged to tag the one I'd like to keep and filter them, looks like quite a workaround the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could try around I realized that the only way to achieve this is to add tags to dynamics I want to keep at hand and filter them in this way.